# How to highlight weekends in Fullcalendar with custom settings in slotduration and slotLabelInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have options `slotDuration` and `slotLabelInterval` customized, because I need to show events in the middle of day. But when I set those options, Fullcalendar does not add `fc-sat` and `fc-sun` classes to weekend days. How I can highlight them anyway?

```
  firstDay: 1,
  slotWidth: 22,
  slotDuration: '12:00',
  slotLabelInterval: '24:00',
  slotLabelFormat: [{ weekday: 'short', day: 'numeric' }],
```

[image]

Comment: Assuming you're using fullCalendar 4, I can't reproduce that. Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/BaoErQY . The classes are still there in the timeGridWeek view

Comment: Can you make a demo which shows the issue? Hard to diagnose or fix it otherwise.

Comment: Here is a live demo of with all of settings - https://jsfiddle.net/4gjzhn2o/ . Unfortunatelly no `fc-sat` or `fc-sun` classes.

Comment: It would have helped to know originally that you were talking about the Timeline view...also your demo didn't work because you didn't include the necessary CSS. I fixed it for you: https://jsfiddle.net/v3bxr8f2/1/ . Anyway I suspect this is by design, since you have got slots of less than 1 day's length. I don't think there is much you can do about it except raise a feature request with the maintainers of fullCalendar - see https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a dirty workaround solution, but it works. The idea is to select `span.fc-cell-text` by the name of day in the header (used czech day names in example), then by its parent `th.fc-widget-header` get a date value of its date and then just a add class to highlight whole column of that date. Because the day is separated by 12 hours, it is needed to highlight date with `T00:00:00` and `T12:00:00` time too.

```
$('span.fc-cell-text:contains("so "), span.fc-cell-text:contains("ne ")').each(function() {
    var date = $(this).parents('.fc-widget-header').data('date');
    $('td[data-date="' + date + '"], td[data-date="' + date.replace('T00:00:00', 'T12:00:00') + '"]').addClass('fc-sat');
 });
```

Another solution I have in my head is to find by server-side script weekend days, but this is much easier and faster to implement.